# How to replace a string on a text file with an incrementing value of that string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

i'm trying to replace in a text document the value "car_000" which its found in the document 100 times, i'm trying to replace car_000 with car_001, car002,car003...car_100,my implementation replaces the last value of "car", soo right now with that code  only replaces car_000 with car_100, or the last value of car that i set using a1

```
a1 = 0
x1 = 0
y1 = 0
z1 = 0
while a1 <= 100:
        if x1 == 9:
            x1 = 0
            y1=y1+1
            if y1 == 9:
                z1 = z1+1
                y1 = 0
        fin = open("try1.txt", "rt")
        fout = open("try3.txt", "wt")
        for string in fin:
            fout.write(string.replace('car_000', 'car_' + str(z1) + str(y1) + str(x1)))
        fin.close()
        fout.close()
        print ('N1=' + str(z1) + str(y1) + str(x1))
        x1= x1 + 1
        a1 = 100 * z1 + 10 * y1 + x1
```

Comment: What is your expected output and what problem are you facing?

Comment: Share the complete code.

Comment: @YashKrishan my expected output, replace car_000 with an incrementing value of car(car_001,car_002...car_100), my code replaces all the strings "car_000" with "car_100"

Comment: Also share the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one should work. I have just splitted every string on `car_000` and joined it in loop putting adequate `car_xxx` in between.

```py
fin = open("try1.txt", "rt")
fout = open("try3.txt", "wt")

car_num = 1
for string in fin:
  splitted_string = string.split('car_000')
  replaced_string = splitted_string[0]

  for i in range(len(splitted_string) - 1):
    replaced_string += 'car_' + str(car_num).zfill(3) + splitted_string[i + 1]
    car_num += 1

  fout.write(replaced_string)

fin.close()
fout.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, here is my solution.
Essentially, just split every line in file and replace the desired pattern with counter.

```
modified_line = []
with open("try1.txt") as f:
    counter = 1
    for line in f:
        temp = []
        for word in line.split(" "):
            if word.strip() == "car_000":
                temp.append("car_{:03d}".format(counter))
                counter += 1
            else:
                temp.append(word.strip())
        modified_line.append(" ".join(temp))

with open("try2.txt", "w") as f:
    for m in modified_line:
        print(m, file=f)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```py
import re
i=0
x="car ojapfijo dfjfppi car pdsjapfifjpfjwpif cat <fdpjpfs carcar"
print(x)
while(len(re.findall("car(?!_\d)", x)) > 0):
    i+=1
    x=re.sub("car(?!_\d)", "car_{}".format(str(i).zfill(3)), x, count=1)
    print(x)
```

And the output:

```py
car ojapfijo dfjfppi car pdsjapfifjpfjwpif cat <fdpjpfs carcar
car_001 ojapfijo dfjfppi car pdsjapfifjpfjwpif cat <fdpjpfs carcar
car_001 ojapfijo dfjfppi car_002 pdsjapfifjpfjwpif cat <fdpjpfs carcar
car_001 ojapfijo dfjfppi car_002 pdsjapfifjpfjwpif cat <fdpjpfs car_003car
car_001 ojapfijo dfjfppi car_002 pdsjapfifjpfjwpif cat <fdpjpfs car_003car_004
```